# Load twice to run spark window ok

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using spark 1.5.1 and I don't know if this is a bug or a feature...

I'm trying to sum a dataframe column using a window. The normal code should be like:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = sqlContext.read.parquet('/tmp/my_file.parquet')

w = Window().partitionBy('id').orderBy('timestamp').rowsBetween(0, 5)
df.select(F.sum(df.v1).over(w)).show()
```

Result:

[image]

That result is wrong ( I'd say that is trash). But, if I 'load' twice...

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = sqlContext.read.parquet('/tmp/my_file.parquet')
df = sqlContext.read.parquet('/tmp/my_file.parquet') # NEW LOAD

w = Window().partitionBy('id').orderBy('timestamp').rowsBetween(0, 5)
df.select(F.sum(df.v1).over(w)).show()
```

The new result is correct:

> [image: Blockquote]

What is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that is a resolved bug for Spark 1.5.1. [This](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11452?jql=project%20%3D%20SPARK%20AND%20fixVersion%20%3D%201.5.2) is the jira tracker of the bug.